# Rcpp in Rstudio, can't cache in memory when parallel if I don't open the cpp file in Rstudio

Tags: caching, parallel-processing, rstudio, rcpp

I met a wired problem but I wonder if I'm asking the correct question:

```
result = parLapply(cl, 1:4, 
                     function(j,rho_list_needed,delta0_needed, 
                              V_iter_s,Sigma_list_needed) {
                       rhoj = rho_list_needed[[j]]
                       delta0_in_cpp = delta0_needed
                       v = as.vector(V_iter_s[,,,j])
                       sigmaj = Sigma_list_needed[[j]]
                       sourceCpp('sample_Z.cpp')#first time complie slow,then cashed
                       return(Sample_Z(rhoj,delta0_in_cpp, v,sigmaj,A,Cmatrix))
                     },rho_list_needed,delta0_needed,
                     V_iter[[s]],Sigma_list_needed)
```

When I was testing my `sample_Z.cpp` with parallel through `parLapply`, the single calculation takes around 1 sec. By parallel, my 4 iterations takes around 1.2 secs, which is a big improvement compared to unparalleled version, which is 8 sec.

There's no problem at all when I run my program yesterday. Just now I noticed a bug and revised my program. To give my PC a fresh environment, I restarted my computer. When started to run my program, I only opened the `.R` file, and run. But it took 9 sec for that parallel, which used to be 1.2 sec. The 9 sec was after warming up my cores, i.e., already sourced the cpp before I time it.

I just don't know where is the bug. Then try to source the cpp file directly in my global merriment,  and I found out that there was no caching at all. The second time took the same time as the first one.

But I accidentally opened the `sample_Z.cpp` in Rstudio, explicitly at the editor. And then, everything works correct now.

I don't know how to search this similar problem on google with what kind of key words and I don't know if opening the cpp file is a must, while I never known before.

Can anyone tell me what's the real issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After restarting your PC, you probably had extra processes running which would have competed for CPU cores that slowed down your algorithm. The fact you're rebooting suggests to me you're not using Linux... but if you are, watch with `top` while starting your code, or equivalent for your platform.